# A sequential number system for Buy/Sell Arrows

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[Here is an example of what I'm visually trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cswF4.png)
I'm trying to achieve a labeling system for the arrows I've plotted. The first arrow should be labeled "1", and if another arrow appears within 12 candles, it should be labeled "2". The next arrow in the sequence should be labeled "3" and so on.

Here is the code

```
@version=5
 
indicator('Multi Timeframe RSI - Overlay zones', shorttitle='RSI Zones', overlay=true)
rsi_mid = 50
rsiHigh = 70
rsiLow = 30

len = input(6, title='Length')
src = input(close, title='Source')
show1m = input(true, title='1m')
show5m = input(true, title='5m')
show15m = input(true, title='15m')
show30m = input(true, title='30m')
show1h = input(true, title='1h')
show4h = input(true, title='4h')
show1D = input(true, title='1D')

rsiCurrent = ta.rsi(src, len)
rsi1m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1', ta.rsi(src, len))
rsi5m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', ta.rsi(src, len))
rsi15m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '15', ta.rsi(src, len))
rsi30m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '30', ta.rsi(src, len))
rsi1h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', ta.rsi(src, len))
rsi4h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', ta.rsi(src, len))
rsi1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', ta.rsi(src, len))

redZone = (rsiCurrent \> rsiHigh and (show5m and timeframe.multiplier \ 5 ? rsi5m \ rsiHigh : true) and (show15m and timeframe.multiplier \ 15 ? rsi15m \ rsiHigh : true) and (show30m and timeframe.multiplier \ 30 ? rsi30m \ rsiHigh : true) and (show1h and timeframe.multiplier \ 60 ? rsi1h \ rsiHigh : true) and (show4h and timeframe.multiplier \ 240 ? rsi4h \ rsiHigh : true) and (show1D and not timeframe.isdaily ? rsi1D \ rsiHigh : true))
greenZone = (rsiCurrent \< rsiLow and (show5m and timeframe.multiplier \ 5 ? rsi5m \ rsiLow : true) and (show15m and timeframe.multiplier \ 15 ? rsi15m \ rsiLow : true) and (show30m and timeframe.multiplier \ 30 ? rsi30m \ rsiHigh : true) and (show1h and timeframe.multiplier \ 60 ? rsi1h \ rsiLow : true) and (show4h and timeframe.multiplier \ 240 ? rsi4h \ rsiLow : true) and (show1D and not timeframe.isdaily ? rsi1D \ rsiLow : true))

sinceRed = ta.barssince(redZone)
sinceGreen = ta.barssince(greenZone)

buy = not greenZone and (sinceGreen \< 2)
sell = not redZone and (sinceRed \< 2)

plotshape((buy), title='Buy', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=#00bbd4)
plotshape((sell), title='Sell', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, color=#673ab7)
```

I tried ta.barrsince statement without any success, this is about as far as my coding knowledge goes, I get the feeling an array or If/else statements are needed for this but not sure how to go about it. Here is my example of what I tried, essentially just plotted lots of arrows with '2' for 12 candles for when ever a buy signal plotted.

```
sinceBuy = ta.barssince(buy)
buy2 = sinceBuy < 11
plotshape((buy2), title='Buy2', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=#00bbd4, text='2')
```